# "bcdedit /dbgsettings NET HOSTIP:123.123.123.123 PORT:50123" is not valid

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, device-driver

To enable kernel debugging using LAN (I'm using appropriate LAN-board), according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542187(v=vs.85).aspx), I should type:

```
bcdedit /dbgsettings NET HOSTIP:123.123.123.123 PORT:50123
```

But I get an error:

```
The debugger type specified is not valid.
...
```

How come (Win7x64) ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the document "Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging over a Network Cable Manually": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346.aspx

> the target computer must be running Windows 8 or later